# pg_query works but pg_query_params doesn't

Tags: php, postgresql

I've been trying to figure this out for ages, and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

This works as intended:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM customers WHERE name IS DISTINCT FROM NULL ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = pg_query($dbconn, $query);
```

But this doesn't work at all. It doesn't even return false. Nothing after it even renders.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM customers WHERE name IS DISTINCT FROM $1 ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = pg_query_params($dbconn, $query, $array(NULL));
```

I'm using PHP 5.3 and Postgresql 8.4.

Comment: Is the statement running server-side? Check `pg_stat_activity`. Any error in the PHP logs?

Comment: pilcrow found the issue down below, it was the extra $ before array causing it to be treated as a variable, so PHP was erring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM customers WHERE name IS DISTINCT FROM $1 ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = pg_query_params($dbconn, $query, $array(NULL));
                                           ^
                                           ^
```

You mean *`pg_query_params(..., array(NULL))`* instead.